# Can I make an import work when a script is called from a different directory and from the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say you have this structure:

```
tools/
   - __init__.py
   - kill_all_mosquitos.py
   - animal_finder.py
```

In `kill_all_mosquitos.py` I have this at the top:

```
import animal_finder
```

If I call `kill_all_mosquitos.py` from the same directory, it works. But if I call it from another directory, it won't.

A solution is to use `import .animal_finder` but then you can't call it anymore from the same directory.

So, the solution people seems to do is to do `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`

But this add all the corrent scripts to some global import.

Also, I'm tempted to just do:

```
try:
    import animal_finder
except ImportError:
    import .animal_finder
```

But is there something better than that ?

Comment: Have you tried adding the directory to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable? It's effectively the same as adding the `sys.path.append()` line to each file. A quick google search should show you how to do this for your operating system.

Comment: @pault as you say, it's the same as sys.path.append and it even force the script user to modify his env, maybe my question could be reduced to "why doesn't python add the script directory to the `PYTHONPATH` by default ?"

Comment: I believe that the directory from which you run the program will be included in the path by default, but not the directory where the program is in.